# What's the difference between "It is time to do something" and " It is a time to do something "?

Tags: difference

What's the difference between "It is time to do something" and " It is a time to do something "?
For example:

> 1. It is ***time*** to welcome a new year.
> 2. It is ***a time*** to welcome a new year.

Comment: Although I have no problems with both choices, I might prefer "It is *the* time to welcome a new year." Waiting for native speakers too.

Comment: It's more idiomatic to say it's time to do something than it's a/the time to do something.

Comment: A related question - https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/476746/a-to-do-or-is-to-do

Answer (score 3):

To add to Maulik V’s answer: It is OK to use ***a time*** to refer to a nonspecific/non-unique time (e.g., “This is a time to celebrate.”; see also “[To every thing there is a season, and a time to every purpose under the heaven](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turn!_Turn!_Turn!)”) and ***the time*** for a specific/unique time (e.g., “It is the time to break the piggy bank open.”;
see also ["The time has come," the Walrus said, "to talk of many things…"](http://www.jabberwocky.com/carroll/walrus.html)) 
I would feel comfortable omitting the article in either case: “It is time to celebrate”
or “It is time to break the piggy bank open.”

Comment: I would be especially comfortable omitting the article in the second case ("It is time to break the piggy bank open"); however, that's not so true if we begin the sentence with _now_: "Now is the time to break the piggy bank open."

Answer (score 1):

It's more idiomatic to say it's time, without an article in front of time, when we use the form it's followed by a past subjunctive or to-infinitive.

It's time to celebrate the New Year.

Answer (score -1):

> We use **a time** for an indefinite period - [Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/time?q=time)

When you are specific about something, you use *the* time. Clearly this is the case in your example.

> *It's **the** time to welcome a new year* (If you are specific about the year, use 'the year').

Comment: But I could see a context such as "December is a special time. It is a time to celebrate a great many religious holidays, it is a time to say goodbye to the past year and it is a time to welcome a new year." In that example (which I just made up), "a time" is still general, as it's not a specific instance of the many Decembers that occur over the course of years.

Comment: @wordsmythe True. They are not specific in your examples but it *is specific* in OP's question! Also, I already said that 'a time' would also fit but if you are specific about *this new year coming*, it should be 'the'.